# Data points for some control variables missing in regression - still feasible?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, multiple-imputation, controlling-for-a-variable

I'm currently working on an event study to examine abnormal returns.

In the first step, I've calculated abnormal returns in regards to a certain type of company event, consisting of roughly 13,000 events and >4,000 firms.

In the second step, I intend to run a regression analysis with several (control?) variables to see whether some of the effect stems from certain aspects of the event.

So far so good, now I'm having the issue that I want to control for 5-6 factors like market capitalization and total enterprise value. Unfortunately, I don't have every single datapoint for every single of the 13,000 events. As an example, for Event 1 I'm missing market capitalization, for Event 2 the total enterprise value, for Event 3 the M/B-ratio and so on.

Question: Can I still run a meaningful regression even though I have a significant number of NA's or am I required to delete every single event with incomplete data? Given the poor data availability for some variables (which I generally still would love to include), that would result in a very large number of deleted events (>7,000).

Comment: You could try to impute the missing values. See for example [Multiple Imputation by Chained Equations (MICE) Explained](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/421545/multiple-imputation-by-chained-equations-mice-explained).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, sorry for the late reply. I've had a look into it, the only problem is that I have several binary control variables (e.g., paid in stock or cash, target company is public or private). In such cases, it seems to me that imputation doesn't make sense.

Comment: There are three options: drop rows/events with missing values; do single value imputation (replace with mean, median, mode, etc.); do multiple imputation. Whether your regression analysis is meaningful if you use only complete data points depends on the reasons the data is missing. Take a look at van Buuren's [Flexible Imputation of Missing Data](https://stefvanbuuren.name/fimd/).

Answer (score 0):

As dipetkov says, [multiple-imputation](/questions/tagged/multiple-imputation) is the best solution here. And imputing binary and categorical variables is both reasonable and quite feasible. [This](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Amelia/vignettes/using-amelia.html) is a vignette that shows how to do this in the R package `Amelia`. And [here](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5&q=%22multiple+imputation%22+binary+variables&btnG=) is a Google scholar search that shows a number of papers about multiple imputation of binary variables, in case you would like to look at the primary literature on the subject.